# Issues in build apk in Displaying google map integration

Tags: android, google-maps

What is this error and how can we solve this when i build the apk for displaying google maps it shows like this.any one solve this error?

```
Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at  https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
```

com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_71\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Answer (score 1):

Try the following as the error mentions dex:

Inside your android bracket{}

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "yourapp-package-here"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionName "1.0.0"
}
```

Then add this as well to the same android namespace:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    incremental true
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

In your dependencies, add this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Then in your AndroidManifest file, set the name of the application to

```
MultiDexApplication
```

That is if you don't already extend `Application`! Otherwise, just set the name to your Custom Application which extends `MultiDexApplication`;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
<application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    ...
</application>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Set the name of the application; you do it like this: android:name=

Comment: i can add like that it shows error in activity tag in mainfest fil

Comment: Do you still need help with this?